# How to close a Form embedded in a panel

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have 4 Forms. Inside `Form1` there are 2 Panels and a button. When I click the `button1` on `Form1`, it opens the `Form2` on the first panel. So inside the `Form2` there are 2 buttons. The `button1_Click` method shows the `Form3` on the second panel of `Form1`. How can I show the `Form4` 
 on the second panel by the method `button2_Click`  from `Form2`?

```
   private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Form4 myForm = new Form4();
        myForm.TopLevel = false;
        myForm.AutoScroll = true;
        var Form1 = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().Where(x => x.Name == "Form1").FirstOrDefault();
        Form1.panel2.Controls.Add(myForm);
        myForm.Show();
    }`
```

This is the code I used to try showing `Form4` on the second panel. But it wont replace  `Form3` that is currently appearing on the second panel of `Form1`. I really don't know what to do. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just `Close` it. What's the problem?

Comment: I wanted to remove the Form3 on the second panel and replace it with Form4. I kinda have no clue on how to do it.

Comment: Just get reference to the form you want to remove. Close() it and then remove from parent.controls

Comment: Of course it doesn't *replace* Form4. All you've done is added a new instance of Form3. You need to retrieve the instance of Form4 (much like you've done to retrieve the instance of Form1, except looking in a different container: `Form1.panel2.Controls`) and close it.

Comment: A form object behaves exactly like any child control when you set its TopLevel property to false.  It is in effect a fat UserControl.  It is up to you to remove anything that already exists on that panel, it is not automatic.  Roughly: `while (Form1.panel2.Controls.Count > 0) Form1.panel2.Controls[0].Dispose();`   **Do** set its FormBorderStyle property to None, you never want to create the impression that it acts like a form.  It sure doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from form 2 you want to be able to load form3 OR form4 inside panel2 ?

```
private Form3 form3 = null;
private Form4 form4 = null;

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (form3 != null)
    {
        Form1.panel2.Controls.Remove(form3);
        form3.Close();
        form3 = null;
    }

    form4 = new Form4();
    form4.TopLevel = false;
    form4.AutoScroll = true;
    var Form1 = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().Where(x => x.Name == "Form1").FirstOrDefault();
    Form1.panel2.Controls.Add(form4);
    form4.Show();
}`
```

and do the same for Form3 (remove and close form4 before creating form3)

Also consider setting your form3 and form4 properties as HansPassant suggested in his comment.